# how to add Tooltip on ant design tab?

Tags: reactjs, antd

i have this code, what i want to do on the tab prop is add Tooltip on the icon:

```
<Tabs.TabPane tab={<Tooltip placement="left" title="adasd"><Icon size="1.2" name="cog" /></Tooltip>} key="map">
  <MapProperties onChange={onChange} canvasRef={canvasRef} />
</Tabs.TabPane>
```

i was expecting for the hover to show but it's not working.  is it possible to add ant design tooltip on tabs pane?

Answer (score 7):

Anuj's answer isn't correct since TabPane should be direct children of Tabs component. I also had such problem and I find out that i can solve it like this:

```
<TabPane
  key="3"
  tab={(
    <Tooltip title="Your hint that appears after user's mouse will be over the tab title">
       <span>tab title</span>
    </Tooltip>
  )}
  disabled={mode === PageMode.NEW}
>
```

tab attribute accepts any ReactNode so we can just wrap our tab name with any component. And tooltip isn't exception.

[Proof that this works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgwUP.png)

Comment: Btw I saw topic starter's solution only now and have no idea why this didn't worked. This works perfect at the moment. I added proof that this work in my answer

Comment: also you should know that if you will follow my way you will face UX problem. Tooltip will show only when we hover right on the text. Will be much better if it would show after hovering in any tab button place. My workaround is to add padding: 12px and margin: -12px to our Tooltip content. It's ugly solution but i didn't find something better

Answer (score 1):

It should be like

```
<Tooltip title="foo">
 <Tabs.TabPane>....</Tabs.TabPane>
</Tooltip>
```

https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#header